# Does the "Fanatic" badge count mobile app traffic?

Tags: discussion, badges

The Stack Exchange app is well-built as far as apps go, and I enjoy using it to participate. Out of curiosity, does activity on the app count towards consecutive log-ons for badges?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it does.  [This was addressed on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191781/300411) a few years ago, and is now working.

My experience confirms what the answer says on that page – I have kept my streak alive on this and other SE sites by using the Android app.  But, it's not sufficient to simply open the app – I have found that it's necessary to actually load a new page each day, otherwise it won't register.

Comment: Thank you! I didn’t plan to just load it, I’ll be participating to the best of my ability. I figure the badge is something good to aim for as a short-term goal in my efforts to grow more in my knowledge of my faith.